# Don't use more than two pluralizable numbers in localizable string

Tags: feature-request, localization, plurals

In some rare cases I see strings in Transifex that contain three numbers. Each number can have three plural forms (one, few, and many). So such string requires 27 translations. For example, [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/135334550?q=key%3Aa96bdb65d7fd5c798bf0347cba2ee68d) / [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=a96bdb):

> [image: few few few]

[**It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!** $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎You've asked $NumQuestions$ questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely. $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎It's been $DaysSinceLastQuestion$ days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait $CalculatedLimit$ days before asking again. Use this time to revisit [your previous questions]($prevQuestionsLink$), editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments. $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎**Recommended reading:** $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎- [tips on asking great questions]($askLink$) as well as our guidance on $br$↩⏎- [which questions are allowed here]($onTopicLink$) $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎**Additional advice** $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎- Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better answers much sooner! $br$↩⏎- We don’t demand perfection, but ***please* make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization**, it really helps! $br$↩⏎- Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them. $br$↩⏎- Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions. $br$↩⏎- Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted. $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these restrictions. $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎**For more information** $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎See: [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?]($link$) $br$$br$↩⏎↩⏎It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just **do your best** to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in $CalculatedLimit$ days!](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/135334550?q=key%3Aa96bdb65d7fd5c798bf0347cba2ee68d)

It's too tedious to make copy-n-paste many times for the long string and not to make a mistake with plural forms.

Moreover, there is at least one string with four numbers in the source part:

1. [$EligibleVoters$ voters were eligible, $VisitedSiteDuringElection$ visited the site during the election, $ViewedElection$ visited the election page, and $Voted$ voted](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/143029774?q=key%3A36604f58571398c045eaa41285efad68) / [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=36604f)

But it's not too long as previous.

Please do not use strings with more than two (one is much better) numbers with plural forms in the localization engine.

Comment: Re *"We don’t demand perfection, but please make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization, it really helps!"*: [Speaking of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences)...

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum is this comment autogenerated?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: I think This_is_NOT_a_forum is just pointing out the irony that a sentence reminding the user to "use proper grammar" contains a grammatical mistake (it's a run-on sentence, as indicated by the linked Wikipedia article  – specifically, it's a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)).